# The square symbol does not appear in the end of proof

Tags: theorems, proof-package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries Proof.}}{}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        blablabla
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
        abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I want to make the "proof title" is bold, so I give the code `\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries Proof.}}{}`. But why after adding this code the square symbol in the end of proof is disappear? How to appearing the square symbol in the end of proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no symbol because you left the final argument in your `\renewenvironment` definition blank. You need to add `\qedsymbol`. You also need to load `amssymb` to get the `$\blacksquare$` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries Proof.}}{\qedsymbol}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        blablabla
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
        abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `amsmath` package should not hardwire `\itshape` in the definition of `amsthm`. Maybe a future release will provide a way to choose the font.

In the meantime, it's not difficult to modify the environment by patching.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
blablabla
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]